# Resampling and Huber-White

Tags: r, multiple-regression, resampling, clustered-standard-errors

I'm trying to implement the "Free Step-Down Resampling Method" described by Westfall and Young in "[Resampling-Based Multiple Testing](http://books.google.es/books?id=nuQXORVGI1QC&printsec=frontcover&hl=es&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)" (algorithm ~2.8 in the text). My goal is to perform a multivariate linear regression.

So, I have an error estimate (from the original sample) like this (using OLS):

$\epsilon = Y - (\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \dots \beta_pX_p)$

[BTW, $X_1 \dots X_p$ are dummy variables.]

In order to resample ($i$ times), I have to do:

$Y_i^* = \epsilon_i^*$

where $\epsilon_i^*$ is a *with replacement* sample from the original $\epsilon$.

Here is the problem:

In my dataset, responses (rows) are clustered (data come from related individuals); so, I would usually have applied Huber-White estimators to account for correlations in OLS-based linear regressions.

I don't know how to proceed here... Should Huber-White estimators be used? If so, how?

Apologies if my question is too simple, but I'm new in resampling methods... I guess the answer is simple, too. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: don't you mean $Y−(\beta_1 X_1+ \beta_2 X_2+ \beta_p X_p)$, and should there be an intercept ($\beta_0$) in there as well? Also fix the stray "epsilon" by adding a \. I'd have put the parentheses and \ in myself but that's not enough characters of change to successfully edit.

Comment: True! I'll add that.

Comment: You still didn't put the parentheses around the $(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + ... + \beta_p X_p)$ which means you're subtracting only the first of those terms and *adding the rest*. a - b + c is NOT the same as a - (b+c), and you really don't mean what you wrote.

Comment: Ok, just a typo... 
 ;)

Comment: White considered heteroskedasticity... at least in his 1980 article. The clustered standard errors are usually named as such without trying to attribute them to a person.

Comment: I removed `clustering` tag. It concerns looking for unknown clusters in the data, and your topic is different.

Comment: Give a better reference to the article you cite.

Comment: As you can infer from the reference indicated in the post, I need to do these analyses in order to correct p-values (for multiple testing) in a multivariate model. 
When you say "clustered standard errors are usually named as such without trying to attribute them to a person", I understand that, once a vector standard errors is obtained from the original data (i.e., $\epsilon$), resampling can be done without correcting for heteroskedasticity when evaluating each permutated model (with $\epsilon_i^*$). Is it true? Sounds strange...

Comment: You seem to be mixing up standard errors (measure of variability of the estimated regression coefficients) and regressions errors ($\epsilon_i$). Resampling residuals with replacement to obtain $\epsilon_i^*$ implicitly assumes that they are i.i.d. If they are not, you need to do something different, and some of these procedures are described in the articles I linked.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate I've made that mistake. Sorry about that. I'll check it more carefully and made some of the corrections of Rao and Wu and the survey package. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually there is a reasonable correspondence between the bootstrap scheme and the sandwich estimator.

1. Simple bootstrap with resampling $\Leftrightarrow$ White's heteroskedasticity robust estimator
2. Block bootstrap with blocks of length $l \Leftrightarrow$ Newey-West estimator with $l$ lags
3. Bootstrap of clusters $\Leftrightarrow$ cluster-corrected standard errors.

To read on clustered bootstraps, start from [Rao and Wu (1988)](http://www.citeulike.org/user/ctacmo/article/582039). Methods of this kind would be implemented in `survey` package (although I am not sure it does the Rao and Wu bootstrap, precisely; my understanding is that `survey` just resamples clusters without the small sample corrections that Rao and Wu introduced). To read about resampling methods in regression analysis, take a look at [Wu (1986)](http://www.citeulike.org/user/ctacmo/article/785121).

Comment: Thanks for your fast responses. I'll read those Rao's and Wu's publications. 
I've put a better reference in the original post.. and I also have a question about the other comment you wrote. Please take a look at it... Regards,

Comment: An implementation of the model I mentioned (even based on the same references) is in `flip`. 
[**Although I do not find `flip` too friendly, so I've prefered either running the original code that appears in the book (for SAS) or re-writting it for R.] 
But I still don't have a sense of where to include corrections for non-heteroskedasticity, if necessary...

Comment: I don't have the book, and I don't know what `flip` is, so I can't help you figuring out what the algorithm does and how to modify it for your situation.

Comment: Dear StasK and dear All, 

Apologies for the delay in getting back to the topic. 
Finally I've realized how to get bootweights using `survey` and then create permutated samples: $\epsilon_i^*$. 

Nonetheless, I'm still unable to figure out whether the original 

$\epsilon = Y - (\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \dots \beta_pX_p)$

must be obtained using Huber-White correction for correlated responses... As you said, 
Simple bootstrap with resampling ⇔ White's heteroskedasticity robust estimator, 
but I don't know how to proceed in this case.

Comment: Similarly, I wonder whether in the next steps, when doing 

$Y_i^* = \epsilon_i^*$

I should, again, use some kind of corrections to account for heteroskedasticity of each case when performing new regressions. 

I hope not to bother you; thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Sandwich-type corrections only affect the standard errors, not the point estimates. In other words, White or similar estimators do not deal with $\beta$ at all, and hence do not deal with the residuals, either.