# Bootstrap robust regression

Tags: regression, spss, bootstrap, robust

I'd like to do a robust hierarchical regression using bootstrapping because regression diagnostics indicate that assumptions of ordinary regression have been violated. I've made a start using the bootstrapping function in SPSS. I'm confused. SPSS provides a "Bootstrap for Coefficients" output (which mirrors the regular "Coefficients" output) but it doesn't provide a "Bootstrap for Model Summary" output (to mirror the regular "Model Summary" output). That is to say, SPSS gives me a bootstrap estimate of whether each of the variables is making a significant contribution to the prediction of Y by testing its regression coefficient, but SPSS doesn't give me a bootstrap estimate of whether the set of variables *taken together* predict Y at better-than-chance levels. Isn't this a bit of problem? I want a robust estimate of the overall model precisely because my data violate assumptions of normal least square regression, and for this reason I can't trust the standard "Model Summary" that SPSS provides. But if no "Bootstrap Model Summary" is provided in its place it would seem that I don't have a robust estimate.

Any clarification about whether 1) I am confused about bootstrapping, or 2) SPSS doesn't provide seemingly crucial output would be much appreciated.

Comment: I only used SPSS once or twice, so i cannot say what it does or not, but i found out a [topic about violation of assumptions in OLS and bootstrap](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56870/is-bootstrapping-standard-errors-and-confidence-intervals-appropriate-in-regress), so pretty much the same. You should have a look, maybe you'll find something interesting.